# Install and start jboss 6 on mac osx lion

Tags: macos, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I have already installed jboss server on my mac, however, i met some problems when i start the server

I go to the jboss_home/bin directory and execute command: ./run.sh to start the server.

It give me: "run.sh: Missing required file: /jboss-6.0.0.Final/bin/run.jar"

Can anyone tell me what's the problem of that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible run.jar is missing from the bin directory? Or is it possible you have some colliding environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to run it from your jboss-6.0.0.Final dir, so

jboss-6.0.0.Final > bin/run.sh